# Covariance type and Generic Cast in swift

Tags: ios, swift

How are you? I'm keep doing my learning journey in swift language. Now, I'm with a blocked with another problem: no covariance type and Generic Cast.

I have a UseCase class

```
    class UseCase<P, R> : ProtocolUseCase {
        typealias P = P
        typealias R = R
        
        func toAny() -> UseCase<Any, Any> {
            return self
        }
      ...
    }
```

and `func toAny() -> UseCase<Any, Any>` generate expection:

> Cannot convert return expression of type 'UseCase<P, R>' to return
> type 'UseCase<Any, Any>'

Somebody can help me with this challenge?

Comment: Well you can't do that. Very few things are covariant in Swift. What problem are you trying to solve by doing this? Perhaps that problem can be solved instead? How is a `UseCase<Any, Any>` useful? Note that it's not safe to put any `P` or `R` in it. You can get `Any`thing out of it, but `Any` isn't really useful unless you know what type it actually is.

Comment: Well I'm building a framework to dispatch use cases for swift. In this specific case, for sequence use cases. To solved, I used a closure. Getting the result creating a new generic output<V> and avoiding the cast.